# check if table is empty in cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to find a way to determine if the table is empty in Cassandra DB.

```
cqlsh> SELECT * from examples.basic ;

 key | value
-----+-------

(0 rows)
```

I am running `count(*)` to get the value of the number of rows , but I am getting warning message, So I wanted to know if there is any better way to check if the table is empty(zero rows).

```
cqlsh> SELECT count(*) from examples.basic ;

 count
-------
     0

(1 rows)

Warnings :
Aggregation query used without partition key

cqlsh>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aggregations, like count, can be an overkill for what you are trying to accomplish, specially with the star wildcard, as if there is any data on your table, the query will need to do a full table scan. This can be quite expensive if you have several records.

One way to get the result you are looking for is the query

`cqlsh> SELECT key FROM keyspace1.table1 LIMIT 1;`

### Empty table:

The resultset will be empty

```
 cqlsh> SELECT key FROM keyspace1.table1 LIMIT 1;

 key
 -----

 (0 rows)
```

### Table with data:

The resultset will have a record

```
cqlsh> SELECT key FROM keyspace1.table1 LIMIT 1;

key
----------------------------------
uL24bhnsHYRX8wZItWM6xKdS0WLvDsgi

(1 rows)
```